# How to add a twitter bootstrap tooltip to an icon

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip

I would like to add a right-tooltip from Twitter Bootstrap to an icon element.

The code is this:

```
<h3>Sensors Permissions <i class="icon-info-sign"></i></h3>
```

I would that, when the cursor is over the icon, a right-tooltip with some information is shown.

Comment: What have you tried? http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#tooltips

Answer (score 134, accepted):

I've recently used it like this:

```
 <i class="icon-ok-sign" rel="tooltip" title="Key active" id="blah"></i>
```

Which produces:

[image]

You set the positioning of the tooltip and other features(delays etc) by declaring it using js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("[rel=tooltip]").tooltip({ placement: 'right'});
});
```

As mentioned in comments, you can find other attributes/options [here](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#tooltips).

Answer (score 17):

You might be forgetting to initialize your tooltips with `.tooltip()`.

The `.tooltip()` function must be called on every element that you want to have a tooltip listener. This is for performance purposes. You can initialize a bunch at once by calling the function on a parent, like so: `$('.tooltip-group').tooltip()`

[**View the initialize function on one element on JSFiddle.**](http://jsfiddle.net/GRyAN/)

## Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#example').tooltip();
});
```

## Markup

```
<h3>
  Sensors Permissions
  <i class="icon-info-sign" data-toggle="tooltip" title="first tooltip" id='example'></i>
</h3>
```

Answer (score 12):

@nickhar's answer, using `data-toggle="tooltip"` tested with Bootstrap 2.3.2 and 3.0 :

```
 <i class="icon-ok-sign" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Key active" id="blah"></i>
```

Which produces:

[image]

You set the positioning of the tooltip and other features(delays etc) by declaring it using js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("[data-toggle=tooltip]").tooltip({ placement: 'right'});
});
```

As mentioned in comments, you can find other attributes/options [here](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#tooltips).

Answer (score 1):

in javascript

```
$(function () {
    $(".has-tooltip-right").tooltip({ placement: 'right'}); 
    $(".has-tooltip-left").tooltip({ placement: 'left'}); 
    $(".has-tooltip-bottom").tooltip({ placement: 'bottom'}); 
    $(".has-tooltip").tooltip(); 
});
```

in html

```
<a href="#" class="has-tooltip-bottom" title="" data-original-title="Tooltip">This link</a> 
and <a href="#" class="has-tooltip" title="" data-original-title="Another link">that link</a>
```